# Composer DAG stops parallelizing when importing google.cloud.aiplatform

Tags: parallel-processing, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I've been having issues developing an Airflow orchestrator that periodically runs multiple processes on Vertex AI. I need the DAG to **parallelize** around 50 tasks. What I've found is that I can't import `google.cloud.aiplatform` and run parallel tasks.
Check the following code, works perfectly until I uncomment the last import.

Is this a quota related issue or should I create a support ticket on GCP?

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from google.cloud import storage 
#import google.cloud.aiplatform

default_args = {
    'owner': 'user',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 2, 1),
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    'test.parallel_pipelines',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    catchup=False,
    concurrency=50    
)

def my_python_task(task_id):
    print(f'Hello World {task_id}')

tasks = []
for i in range(50):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'task_{i}',
        python_callable=my_python_task,
        op_kwargs={'task_id': f'task_{i}'},
        dag=dag
    )
    tasks.append(task)

tasks
```

Comment: Is there an error/stacktrace you can share with your inquiry ?

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr Sadly I get no error. The issue is that I can't import or use the aiplatform library and run parallel airflow tasks on Composer only when I comment the library I get to run them on parallel.

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr Keep in mind the example code is not my productive code. I am indeed using methods from the ai platform library